# Should I immediately return MOSFETS shipped in non-ESD protective packaging?

Tags: mosfet, esd

Recently I ordered 100x IRLZ44N power MOSFETs through an eBay vendor based in the US. Today I received the package, and they were simply wrapped in bubble wrap and taped shut. This is obviously not proper packaging for ESD-sensitive parts like MOSFETs.

Should I immediately return the parts? Or should I try some and see if they work?

Thanks for advice. Below is an image of what the shipment looked like. On the left are the packages in question, and on the right is what I would expect for ESD-sensitive device shipping.

[image]

Comment: Up to you, there's a chance that probably some or even most of them will work, but it's a gamble. If they were cheap enough and you know how to test them maybe it's not a bad deal.  I personally would never buy components from eBay, but to each their own.

Comment: Well just because some shipped in an ESD bag doesn't mean the supply chain up to that point is ESD compliant, so its still a gamble with the parts in an ESD bag.

Comment: @sstobbe If you  buy from a reputable distributor or direct from a manufacturer you can be sure that packaging is ESD compliant.  With EBay, not so much.

Comment: @JohnD Exactly! With Ebay all bets are off. Even if the parts come in an ESD bag they may well have been hand picked from a bucket dumped out on the carpet.

Comment: @sstobbe Ouch, that mental image is killing me a little... anyway, I've been testing them and, somewhat surprisingly, 70 of the 100 so far are good.

Comment: @sstobbe LOL, agreed!

Comment: @JohnD Out of curiousity, would you buy resistors/capacitors/other passive non-ESD components from eBay? Or would you not even do that?

Comment: I typically go to Digikey's website and look at the products and buy straight from the recommended manufacturer.

Comment: No, I would not buy any electronic components from eBay.  I would stick to the reputable distributors like Digi-Key, etc.  However, I'm not a hobbyist and I can understand why some people might want to save some money buy being from eBay.

Comment: You should crack a few open to compare the dies between the ones from your "reputable dealer" and the ones from ebay. See (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDWEa.jpg)

Comment: what are we trying to achieve here?

Comment: Are you claiming that you can see ESD damage on the die with the naked eye? Because this question is about ESD damage.

Comment: It seems to be about a blanket suspicion about ebay parts that come in dodgy packaging being reclaimed (good enough for some hobbyist purposes) or downright counterfeit (bad for everyone)... mind that the transistors shown are bipolar, not mosfets ;)

Comment: I'm simply attracting OP's attention to the fact that buying semiconductors on ebay carries much higher risk of getting counterfeits than from a proven/reputable outlet... Considering the dodgy packaging... who knows? Crack one open from the "known good" ones and one from the "suspect" ones, and check if the die looks the same. I buy from ebay/aliexpress stuff like "book of 100 SMD resistors of each value in the series for dirt cheap" (1% thin film from yageo they say... yeah riiiiiiiight, sure but who cares)

Comment: There is some great stuff on Ebay, especially from China. As an example, I have some 10 watt LEDs that are so efficient they only draw less than 1 watt of power. The mainstream companies don't even have them in stock.

Comment: Well, I did buy TOSLINK transceivers from aliexpress, but the seller was the manufacturer themselves, and they did perform excellently. But when the same store sells electronic stuff, dog food, medicinal herbs, and gardening accessories... weeeelll...

Comment: Let's keep it real: ESD concerns are basically hype for hobby-level "engineers" at that price point. if you get a few bad ones, who cares, it's not like you're feeding a pick and place cranking out expensive production units with potentially costly undiscovered flaws. For such low-volume pricing, it's probably worth it test them out before integration, which is cost-prohibitive in a production environment. If all it means to you is popping it in a component tester before building your sunday afternoon project, that's well-worth the dice-roll imho. Still, I've gotten irfz44n ebayed as irlz44n.

Answer (score 7):

Bad news. Beside of catastrophic failures, which can be detected by 
normal inspection, ESD damage to electronic components can lead 
also to latent defects, which cannot. Partially degraded components
may randomly shorten the lifetime of equipments, do not use them in
critical applications.

Answer (score 5):

You could test all the mosfets, but I suspect that none of them are damaged. I have received IRLB8743 mosfets in a plastic bag many times before, and have never discovered a dud mosfet in the batch.

Test circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frSEG5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED should be on, and should go off when the button is pressed. If the mosfet passes this test, then it is probably OK.

[EDIT] I recently received some IRF3205s in a plastic bag and one of them was dead on arrival. Don't trust components in a plain plastic bag unless you test them.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Just wired up a similar test circuit (gate tied to ground, switch connected to VCC) and all the ones I've tested so far (around 25) are working. I guess I won't return them.

Comment: I've had them supplied both ways and not found any failures in the non-ESD ones. However, as has been noted on other discussions here, I live in England, a notoriously damp country. I suspect there would be a failure rate in drier climes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should return them,  most mosfet gates are nm thick and are some of the thinnest parts of a fet. Because of this it doesn't take much to blow through
[image]
Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312332929_Impact_of_back_plane_doping_on_RF_performance_of_FD-SOI_transistor/figures?lo=1

Here is a picture of what can happen to a fet with an ESD discharge.

[image]
Source: [TI ESD falures ssya010 (a good read)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwicgfX6gePbAhWQCHwKHRiTDkUQFggrMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fan%2Fssya010a%2Fssya010a.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3gKIwtg44zjVdNshaAAbsx)

Most modern FETs come with some kind of ESD protection, some older fets without protection could be destroyed by waving your hand over them.

The problem with ESD is you don't know what will happen, it could fail after you put it on the board, or months from now. If you know a device has been exposed to an ESD field all bets are off, you don't know if the device is damaged or not, so get parts that you know are good from the manufacturer.